# periods not available in keypad to enter in edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText, where I need to enter price. I need to show $ symbol before the digits and two decimal after period(.55) and period should be once. I used the following code. But when I hit "." it doesn't appear in the EditText.

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextForAddItemPrice"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                 android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                  android:digits="0123456789.,$"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textForAddItemPrice"
                    android:background="@color/app_bg_color"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/txt_color_gray"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />

editTxtForPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isEdiging;
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  String sText = editTxtForPrice.getText().toString();
                if(s.length()>0)
                {
                 if(isEdiging) return;
                    isEdiging = true;

                    String str = s.toString().replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
                    if(!str.equals(""))
                    {
                    double s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);

                    NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("$ ###,###.###");
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));


                    }
                    isEdiging = false;  
                    }
            }  
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a textwatcher, which solved my problem.

```
editTxtForPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {

                    editTxtForPrice.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                    String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

                    double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                    String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
                            .format((parsed / 100));

                    current = formatted;
                    editTxtForPrice.setText(formatted);
                    editTxtForPrice.setSelection(formatted.length());

                    editTxtForPrice.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }

            }
```